# Why is MongoDB slower to insert Records only when collection does not exist?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I was doing the benchmarking of MongoDB 3.2.17
 for fun and cannot understand the reason for this behavior.

- When I create an empty collection prior to doing insertion

  > MongoDB x 906 ops/sec ±2.78% (75 runs sampled)
- When I don't create any empty collection and just simply run `insertMany`

  > MongoDB x 87.81 ops/sec ±94.31% (71 runs sampled) // **Error Rate is high, why?**

My Code that uses Benchmark.js so that you can point if I made some mistake there

```
var Benchmark = require('benchmark');
var suite = new Benchmark.Suite;
const MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
var collectionMongodb = 'testrecords2';
Promise.all([
    MongoClient.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/testme') 
]).then((clients) => {
    var nativeCollection = clients[0].db('testmongodb').collection(collectionMongodb)
    var records = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
        records.push({
            name: 'bugwheels' + i,
            interest: 'Not Many',
            job: 'Useless'
        })
    }
    suite
    .add('MongoDB', {
        defer: true,
        fn: function(def) {
            nativeCollection.insertMany(records, (e, r) => {
                def.resolve();
                // console.log(r)
            })
        }
    })
    .on('cycle', function(event) {
        console.log(String(event.target));
    })
    .on('complete', function() {
        console.log('Fastest is ' + this.filter('fastest').map('name'));
//          nativeCollection.drop()
    })
    .run({ 'async': true });    
})
```

Please, let me know what has gone wrong?

My StorageEngine

```
{
    "name" : "wiredTiger",
    "supportsCommittedReads" : true,
    "persistent" : true
 }
```

I started mongoDB using:

```
mongod --dbpath ./db
```

Comment: What version of MongoDB are you using, and which storage engine?

Comment: Can't reproduce it on 3.6.2. How do you create an empty collection? via db.createCollection in a separate shell? So in case 1) you just create the collection and run your script, in the other case don't create it and run the same script again?

Comment: you say "Error Rate is high" - it would help to know what those errors are.  And also how are you resetting the environment between runs?  Creating entire new mongod instance?  What options? replication? auth?  etc.

Comment: @ffeast exactly

Comment: @AsyaKamsky I have not reset any environment. Just insert, insert and insert as there is only one test in the benchmark. I have not set any replication. No auth. Edited question

Comment: I've pulled a fresh mongodb 3.2.4 docker image and ran your script as you described. The results are 663 ops/sec ±5.73% and 676 ops/sec ±5.25% so I'd assume something is either missing in your question or your environment. Can you double-check it in a clean environment?

Comment: Could you please repeat your test and make sure that your results are reproducable? If you did test only once - there are so many reasons why one test run is much slower...

Comment: @ffeast May you please check if you have also made the mistake that my code has. Refer to the answer in that case. Anyways, your results are ok with the error too

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is quite simple.  You are inserting the same 100 records in every run.

When you drop the collection between every run, you are measuring how long it takes to drop collection and then insert 100 documents into it.

When you comment out dropping the collection, you insert the 100 records in the first run, but then your subsequent runs are each attempting to insert the exact same 100 documents into the same collection and they are all getting the error:

```
exception: E11000 duplicate key error collection: testmongodb.testrecords2 index: _id_ dup key: { : ObjectId('5aa19388df671d3a065076f5') } code:DuplicateKey
```

I assume that the way you are creating empty collections actually causes the amount of work to vary significantly so one thing you should do is make sure you are benchmarking correctly by generating unique records every time.

Comment: By the way, the driver adds _id and unique index on _id is automatically created as soon as a collection exists.

Comment: Let's have a calm discussion into finding out the issue then instead of proving each other wrong.:) May you please tell me your mongoDB version, I'll check. Logically asking, do you really think that this should throw an error? Does it really matter if they are same object in JS **without _id**?

Comment: Logically, the version is irrelevant. The error is being returned to the client. All I did was increase the verbosity of logging and let you what your code is actually doing when you run it. You can do the same thing. In the shell type db.setLogLevel(1) and then run your program.

Comment: And see my note about _id which is added by the driver.  So if you resend the same batch of documents they will be duplicates of ones already inserted.

Comment: You are right. The error was being thrown. I saw that it was indeed 100 records in my DB, maybe I was drunk when I saw more than 100 records. The results are also consistent now after generating records in each cycle. Thanks!